# Why does function taking char pointer pointer not work?

Tags: c, function, pointers, char

I'm stuck and can't figure out why this function code won't work properly. The code is from an irc client sending data to the server.

This code works:

```c
void write_socket(char msg[512]) {
    ////////  Convert from unicode to encoding  ////////
    iconv_t cd = iconv_open(encoding, "UTF-8");
    char buffer[512];
    char *outptr = (char *) &buffer[0];
    size_t insize  = 512;
    size_t outsize = 512;
    iconv(cd, &msg, &insize, &outptr, &outsize);
    msg = buffer;
    printf("(%lu) msg: %s\n", strlen(msg), msg);
    int n = write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (n < 0)
        error("Error writing to socket");
}
```

When I call `write_socket("NICK kiyoshi\r\n");`
it gives this output: `(14) msg: NICK kiyoshi`
and successfully connects to the server.

This code does not work:

```
void write_socket(char *msg) {
    encode(&msg, 512);
    printf("encode: (%lu) msg: %s\n", strlen(msg), msg);
    int n = write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (n < 0)
        error("Error writing to socket");
}

void encode(char **str, int size) {
    if (*encoding) {
        ////////  Convert from unicode to encoding  ////////
        iconv_t cd = iconv_open(encoding, "UTF-8");
        char buffer[size];
        char *outptr = (char *) &buffer[0];
        size_t insize  = size;
        size_t outsize = size;
        iconv(cd, &(*str), &insize, &outptr, &outsize);
        *str = buffer;
    }
}
```

When I call `write_socket("NICK kiyoshi\r\n");`
it gives this output: `encode: (14) msg:`
and never connects to the server.

What is wrong with the char pointer? I would like to use the function `encode`.

Comment: in case you're unaware, `char *msg` means exactly the same as `char msg[512]` in that context

Comment: @M.M yes, I had it as `char msg[512]` and it wasn't working either

Comment: should you be calling `iconv_close(cd)` after conversion? Actually, you are not checking for the return value of `iconv`.

Comment: @t0mm13b Thanks, I'll do that

Comment: char *msg; should be const char *msg;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version fails because you point `*str` to a buffer that is local  to the `encode` function.  Local variables stop existing when a function returns, unless they are marked `static`.  So by the time the code gets to `int n = write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg))`, the `msg` is a dangling pointer.

One fix would be to declare `buffer` in the `write_socket` function, and pass the buffer to `encode`.

Answer (score 0):

in function **encode**, variable **buffer** is local variable, local variable is store in stack, after the end of calling function **encode**, the content is gone too.